# Compare Java and GPars

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, gpars

I'm trying to find a comparable code snippet for both Java and GPars to visualize, how much easier GPars is.
Does the following code do the same in both cases? I don't mean the output only, but also what happens "inside".
Or is there a way to shorten it even more?

Java:

```
package java;

public class Main extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Main()).start();
    }

}
```

Groovy:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

withPool{
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        println (i)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Groovy code snippet, 
You should use **eachParallel** instead of **for(...)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example creates a new Thread, and runs a for loop inside it (the loop gets all the way through as the thread is not a daemon thread, so the VM will not exit until the thread completes)

The second example calls `withPool`, then does nothing with this pool, and just runs the for loop in the current thread.  You are not making use of any of the GPars concurrency methods, so the `withPool` can be omitted for the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare Java (language) and GPars (library). You can compare language and language, or library and library. GPars can be used directly from Java, by the way. What you probably meant is to compare standard java library with GPars.